# Multithread: Dynamically object locking based on resource in hava

Tags: java, multithreading, java.util.concurrent

Need threads expert eyes here...

I am on a poc app where i am uploading files on FTP server

In FTP server have multiple folders. Based on input response I reads files from the folder and move to another folder

The app can access by multiple threads at a time.

So the problem was this:

Suppose FTP have a folders Folder_A and A_A_FOLDER
Now Folder_A have 10 files.
a thread came and read 10 files from FTP and start some calculation on it,
it calculated one by one and then move to  A_A_FOLDER
it was middle in the process (let suppose it successfully moved 5 files from Folder_A to A_A_FOLDER)
then another thread came and it picks remaining 5 files because they were underprocessed by thread 1, so thread 2 also start processing those 5 files

So duplicate files problem here

```
void m1(String folderName) {
// FTP related code
}
```

I have solved this problem by using **synchronized** keyword

Now every thing in sync and all processing working fine

```
synchronized void m1(String folderName) {
// code
}
```

**folderName** decide which folder need to process

Now I have started facing performance issue

because the method is synchronized so all thread going to wait until processing thread not completed its task.

I can improve this by following steps:

(Before going to a solution here is the some story to much dig on the problem)

As I have mentioned  folderName parameter of m1 method decide which folder will process, 
So suppose I have 4 folders (A, B, A_T, B_T) in Ftp server, 2 folders are those where data need to read from (A and B),
And 2 folder are those where data will move (A_T and B_T)

A_T and B_T is not the concern here because they are unique for each folder A and B
So if the method will read from A then it will move it to A_T same for B (move to B_T)

Now:

Suppose 4 thread comes to m1 method, 3 threads for folder A and 1 for folder B
if somehow method synchronized request based on fileName parameter so I can improve the performance, means 1 thread will work on A another 2 threading will block because fileName is same for them so they will wait until first thread not completed it task where thread 4 will parallel work without any locking process because it's file name is different

So how can I achieve this(synchronized on fileName) in code level?

Note: i know i can break this logic using static locking list for resource and then the locks  fileName resource 
e.g:

```
private final Object A = new Object();
private final Object B = new Object();
```

but the problem with this approach is folder can be dynamically added, so I can't go with this.

Need your help guys.

Comment: You can use a `ConcurrentHashMap<String, CountDownLatch>` where keys are file names and values are instances of `ne CountDownLatch(1)`. One thread doing the move controls the latch and counts it down, other threads wait for the latch only if it is not counted down and only for their file name. Give it a try and if you do not succeed I will write you an example

Comment: Your use of FTP is a fundamental problem, as under FTP there is no way to know a file transfer has been completed.  A transfer may fail part way through and then either restart or continue from where it left off, and no signal or sign is available when a transfer "finishes".  You can never be 100% sure what you see in the server's upload directory is usable.  You should migrate to `rsync` instead, which can be configured to write to a temporary and create the final file only when all data is received.

Comment: @JimGarrison  I appreciate  your response, But here main problem is not FTP, i have implemented the flow of FTP, and it also not my concern, here main point is Multi Threading controlling this kind of scenario. Because there are many cases where this kind of problem can be occur in case of multi threading. So i am curious about handling this issue in multithread env

Comment: @OlegSklyar i have added the fully working solution below could you please review it. Is there any suggestion(do i need any additional work around it) from your side, will appreciable. 
Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach would to be maintain a lock per directory:

```
public class DirectoryTaskManager {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        DirectoryTaskManager manager = new DirectoryTaskManager();
        manager.withDirLock(new File("Folder_A"), () -> System.out.println("Doing something..."));
    }

    public void withDirLock(File dir, Runnable task) throws IOException {
        ReentrantLock lock = getDirLock(dir);
        lock.lock();
        try {
            task.run();
        } finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }

    private Map<File, ReentrantLock> dirLocks = Collections.synchronizedMap(new HashMap<>());

    public ReentrantLock getDirLock(File dir) throws IOException {
        // Resolve the canonical file here so that different paths 
        // to the same file use the same lock
        File canonicalDir = dir.getCanonicalFile();
        if (!canonicalDir.exists() || !canonicalDir.isDirectory()) {
            throw new FileNotFoundException(canonicalDir.getName());
        }
        return dirLocks.computeIfAbsent(canonicalDir, d -> new ReentrantLock());
    }
}
```

Comment: thump up : @teppic thank you man for your guidance. I have added fully working example below could you please review it

Comment: Nice answer. Any reason for using Collections.synchronizedMap than a ConcurrentHashMap?

Comment: @Sneh: I prefer `Collections.synchronizedMap` in most cases. `ConcurrentHashMap` sacrifices consistency for read speed and has more complicated locking semantics.

Comment: I see your point but syncronizedMap performance really suffers due to object level locking. Its doesn’t make much of a difference in this answer as only computeIfAbsenr is invoked. This is a good read https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp08223/index.html

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @teppic and @OlegSklyar for your direction
Finally here is full working example,

FolderImpl -> have method name call which can accessed by many threads

I have used ConcurrentHashMap(Reads can happen very fast while write is done with a lock.) which is lil faster then synchronizedMap
which will hold the folder name and a ReentrantLock, so lock will work on folder name

```
public class FolderImpl {
    private FolderImpl(){
        System.out.println("init................");
    }

    private ConcurrentHashMap<String, ReentrantLock> concurrentHashMap= new ConcurrentHashMap();
    private static final FolderImpl singleTon = new FolderImpl();
    public static FolderImpl getSingleTon() {
        return singleTon;
    }

    public void call(String name) throws Exception{
        ReentrantLock getDirLock = getDirLock(name);
        getDirLock.lock();
        try {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i ++) {
            System.out.println(i+":"+name+":"+Thread.currentThread().getName());
            try {
                Thread.sleep(30);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }}finally {
            getDirLock.unlock();
        }

    }

    public ReentrantLock getDirLock(String site)  {
        return concurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent(site, d -> new ReentrantLock());
    }
}
```

TaskCaller thread call the call method, here is sleep flavor so another thred can git execution time

```
public class TaskCaller extends Thread{
    public FolderImpl singleTon = FolderImpl.getSingleTon();
    public TaskCaller(String name) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
    }

    private String name;
    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            System.out.println("Name:"+Thread.currentThread().getName());

            try {
                singleTon.call(name);
                sleep(10);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

TestExecution class will execute 10 number of thread for testing

```
public class TestExecution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TaskCaller testThreadCC = new TaskCaller("A_FOLDER");
        TaskCaller testThreadCC2 = new TaskCaller("A_FOLDER");
        TaskCaller testThreadCC3 = new TaskCaller("B_FOLDER");
        TaskCaller testThreadCC4 = new TaskCaller("C_FOLDER");
        TaskCaller testThreadCC5 = new TaskCaller("C_FOLDER");
        TaskCaller testThreadCC6 = new TaskCaller("C_FOLDER");
        TaskCaller testThreadCC7 = new TaskCaller("A_FOLDER");
        TaskCaller testThreadCC8 = new TaskCaller("A_FOLDER");
        TaskCaller testThreadCC9 = new TaskCaller("B_FOLDER");
        TaskCaller testThreadCC10 = new TaskCaller("B_FOLDER");

        testThreadCC.start();
        testThreadCC2.start();
        testThreadCC3.start();
        testThreadCC4.start();
        testThreadCC5.start();
        testThreadCC6.start();
        testThreadCC7.start();
        testThreadCC8.start();
        testThreadCC9.start();
        testThreadCC10.start();

    }

}
```

Comment: Choice of locking mechanism can make a big difference by the way. Read this https://blog.takipi.com/java-8-stampedlocks-vs-readwritelocks-and-synchronized/

Comment: @Sneh thanks, blog is wealthy  but  here StampedLock or ReentrantReadWriteLock not filling up my requirement, they can be but they are not efficient for this kind of scenario.In These Locking policies are best for allows the read lock to be held simultaneously by multiple reader threads, as long as there are no writers, and the write lock is exclusive.